# How to name an array with incoming string at java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to do an student registration system.

I'm asking "class id" and "class quota" to user in somewhere in program. After that I'll send students to that lesson according to its quota.

I think, I need an array whose name is user's class id and whose size is  user's quota. For example if user enter "a1" as class name and "10" as quota. I should have an array a1[10].

to do that I've written:

```
public static void create_course_list(String id,int kota)
{
    Student[] id=new Student[kota];       
}
```

first parameter is class id and second is its quota.

but I can't name "id" this array. I guess the compiler thinks I'm trying to name this array just "id", not the inside of "id". how can I name this array, what id holds inside of it.

To summarize: I want to create an array whose name is whatever user send me.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a `Map` instead.

```
Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
data.put("a1", 10);
data.get("a1");//will return 10
```